# Elementary operation on determinant, but actually basic algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $\begin{vmatrix} -1 & a & a \\ b & -1 & b \\ c & c & -1 \end{vmatrix} =0$  then what's the value of $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b} +\frac{1}{1+c}$$

I just expanded the Determinant, to get
$$ab+bc+ac+2abc=1$$

Which further leads to $$\frac{1+a}{a}+\frac{1+b}{b}+ \frac{1+c}{c}= 1+\frac{1}{abc}$$

The solution in the book uses elementary operations, but is it possible to make the "original"  equation of determinant in the required form?
[image]

This maybe a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: If you really want to brute-force it, maybe try to set the third column as a linear combination of the other two columns, thus getting an extra equation? I haven’t tried it though.

Comment: That's what the solution has done, I'm just asking if it is possible to (easily) modify the actual equation, @Benjamin Wang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $$c=\frac{1-ab}{a+b+2ab}$$ we get $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1-ab}{a+b+2ab}}=2$$ after a few simplifications.

Comment: This is my first posting after a was banned.

Comment: Not the way I was expecting. But I'm satisfied.thanks

Comment: Ok, but what do you exspect?

Comment: I think my solution is very short.

Comment: No no, your solution is all good.

Comment: I don't know, ask the moderators.

Comment: "I don't know"??? Your public ban message made it explicitly clear it was for "low quality contributions" – and it wasn't even the first time you were banned for that very reason. I would seriously hope, after the bans and all the criticism that you've received since your first posts on this website, that you've at least gained some self-awareness. "I don't know" is not a very encouraging sign.